# iOS7: Hiding and showing of UIView not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uiview

I have a `UIView` on my `UIViewController` and it is correctly connected

[image]

It is also made `hidden` by default as
[image]

The idea is to show the view only when the model property is set. The code for that looks like

```
    if (budgetCategoryModel.recurring) {
        [self.recurringView setHidden:NO];
    }
```

When I inspect, I see
[image]

But the view doesn't renders on the `UIViewController` at all,

[image]

What is that I am missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you step through to confirm the setHidden line is being executed?

Comment: @MikeTaverne, Yes, is it executing the statement, I just re-confirmed

Comment: If you make it not hidden by default in the storyboard, does it show up?

Comment: Are you sure that view is hidden? Maybe that background color's view is white

Comment: try to change the BG color to red(or any-other)of that view and call`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView]`.  this will help you in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I just caught the bug in my code.

The code

```
    if (budgetCategoryModel.recurring) {
        [self.recurringView setHidden:NO];
    }
```

was executing inside `init` method.

when I executed the method inside `viewDidLoad`, I get to see the right behavior

Thanks for suggesting different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you (or xCode) can make mistake during connecting `IBOutlets/IBAction` so if it doesn't work you can remove connection and it back again, mostly it should help.

Also **Apple recommendation** is use `weak` instead of `strong/retain` for `IBOutlet` property so if you haven't got a good reason you should do:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *yourview;
```

then,

```
[yourview setHidden:NO];

[yourview setHidden:YES];
```

This might helps you :)